# Business days in Pandas: EU, USA, or another?

Tags: time-series, pandas

To create a pandas date range I usually do the following:

```
pd.date_range("1991-01-01","1998-01-01",freq="B")
```

where pd is the pandas import, and freq="B" makes the frequency to be "Business Days".

In the [R Dataset Documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/datasets/versions/3.6.2/topics/EuStockMarkets), the EuStockMarkets is said to have been collected at between 1991 and 1998.

1. pd.date_range("1991-01-01","1998-01-01",freq="B") results in 1828 dates, while the R dataset has 1860. Why is that? What are the differences?
2. I find very strange that R Dataset has collected data from different EU countries, which have different holidays, in just 1 and only 1 date index...
3. Pandas only returns one time series. Is this business days in the USA, the EU(whatever this may mean), or it depends on the system where I run the pandas command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the difference in the number of days between the two is that the `EuStockMarkets` dataset does not range from 1-1-1991 to 1-1-1998 but from 1-7-1991 to 14-08-1998 so you are comparing two different time ranges.

```
> time(EuStockMarkets)
Time Series:
Start = c(1991, 130) 
End = c(1998, 169) 
Frequency = 260
```

Using the actual dates when calculating the number of business days in the range using timeanddate.com gives 1860 when including public holidays. So while the documentation notes that it excludes holidays that doesn't seem to actually be the case. This might be linked to your second point regarding the different holidays at only one index.

For `pandas.date_range` the days returned seem to simply only be the weekdays, i.e. Monday through Friday, which include any holidays. If you want to exclude holidays in your python version you can [use any of the existing calendar classes or create a custom one yourself](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#holidays-holiday-calendars) in combination with [`pandas.bdate_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.bdate_range.html).

Comment: Many thanks for the research ;)